# Using extern @class in order to add a category?

Tags: objective-c, class, import, extern

Is there a way to "promise that a class exists elsewhere" (i.e. similar to the [extern keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946296/use-of-extern-in-objective-c)) and therefore avoid having to use `#import` statements?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
extern @class MyClass;

@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) MyClass *abc;
@end
```

Where `MyClass` definitely exists and is used throughout my program, but at the time I create this file, I don't know the name of the file where `MyClass` is defined.

**Update**: It seems like the error is related to the fact that this is a category. Updated code follows:

```
@class MyClass;

@interface MyClass (Extensions)
- (void)foo;
@end
```

Gives the following error:

> Cannot define category for undefined class 'MyClass'.

Comment: I added to my answer below, but you cannot forward declare for a category because the compiler must be able to see the real class to add to it.

Comment: Dude, you completely changed the question.

Comment: @Chuck: Yeah, it won't let me delete it, and this resolves the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "forward declare" a class by simply doing:

```
@class MyClass;
```

When you actually go to use the class though, you will still need to import the header.

However, you must use an import when subclassing or adding a category for the class. The compiler must be able to see the real class in order to modify or extend it.

Your only option to "extend" a class that you can't import directly into a file would be to modify the class at runtime using the objective-c runtime library. You could create another class and then add the methods from that class to the real class at runtime.

Basically you would use NSClassFromString to get the class and then use [class_addMethod](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod) to add those methods to the real class.

This is almost certainly overkill for anything you would want to do though.

Comment: @class seems to only work if the class is defined in the same file.

Comment: Seems like it might be specific to implementing a category, then. Updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Yes exactly, you cannot subclass or add a category to a forward declared class.

Comment: @Senseful I added a brief description of your only way to achieve something close to what you are looking for. (Adding methods to a class that you don't know of its existence until runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what the `@class` directive is for (without the `extern` part).

Comment: @class seems to only work if the class is defined in the same file.

Comment: @Senseful: No, it'll work without knowing the file. Could even be a class that doesn't exist in the project.

Comment: Seems like it might be specific to implementing a category, then. Updated the question to reflect that.